# How to go through each element in JSON array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, echo

I want  to echo out each element of an object of a JSON array like this:

```
{"request_list":[{"id":"1","name":"yunus","surname":"smsk","phone_number":"05350601922","blood_type":"0","unit_of_blood":"0","date":null},{"id":"3","name":"yunus","surname":"smsk","phone_number":"05350601922","blood_type":"0","unit_of_blood":"0","date":null}]}
```

But i cannot do it.I tried somethinglikethis:

```
$object = json_decode($json, true);
$request_list = $object->request_list;
foreach($request_list as $r){
    echo $r->name;
    echo $r->blood_type;
    echo $r->phone_number;
}
```

But I got an error like:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Get rid of the true as the second argument in json_deocde, by setting true you convert objects to arrays.

Comment: if second argument is true, Json will be converted as php array. remove second argument in json_decode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mark return as array true in `json_decode`. So, try below code.

```
 $object = json_decode($json, true);
 $request_list = $object['request_list'];
 foreach($request_list as $r){
    echo $r['name'];
    echo $r['blood_type'];
    echo $r['phone_number'];
}
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT IT WORKED DAMN WELL BRO sandeepsure

Comment: @YunusSımsıkı Mark answer as accepted. So, it will easy for others to adapt this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$object = json_decode($json, true);
$request_list = $object['request_list'];
foreach($request_list as $r){
    echo $r['name'];
    echo $r['blood_type'];
    echo $r['phone_number'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    $json = '{"request_list":[{"id":"1","name":"yunus","surname":"smsk","phone_number":"05350601922","blood_type":"0","unit_of_blood":"0","date":null},{"id":"3","name":"yunus","surname":"smsk","phone_number":"05350601922","blood_type":"0","unit_of_blood":"0","date":null}]}';
    $data = json_decode($json );

    $request = $data->request_list;

    foreach($request as $request_data){
        echo $request_data->id;
        echo $request_data->name;
        echo $request_data->surname;
    }
```